# No vertices on skin modifier

Tags: modifiers

I added a skin modifier. I can't see or select the vertices. What's wrong?[image]

[image]

Comment: Presumably there are only two verts. One will be at the centre of the 3D cursor and the other is visible at the top of your edge. [Upload](https://blend-exchange.com/help) your file if you want someone to have a look.

Comment: I've uploaded the file

Answer (score 1):

When modifiers generate geometry, you can't access the generated geometry until you have applied the modifier.

Comment: Do I apply both the skin and subdivision modifier?

Comment: Try and see what's better for you.

Comment: Err. You certainly can access the two verts in @Martin's file! I've just downloaded his file and selected both of them without applying any modifiers and can move them around without problems

Comment: Thanks a lot. Figured it out later